# Securing ASP.NET Core Web API with Azure AD

Tags: asp.net, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I am trying to start a new project that uses Azure AD for authentication. It is set up so that I have a SPA on the front end that gets information from an ASP.NET core web API, both of which I am creating. I am having trouble getting the front end token to authorize in the API. Every time I send a request to the API I get the error: `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: IDX10231: Audience validation failed`.

I have set up the project as following.

In Azure AD I have set up two applications: One for the front end and one for the API. The API application has an API exposed called `access_as_user`. The front end application then has access to this. I have also made a client secret for both and added redirect URL's for the front end.

In my ASP.NET core API I am using I'm using `Microsoft.Identity.Web` and calling it like so:

```cs
// startup.cs

...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    ...
    services.AddProtectedWebApi(Configuration, subscribeToJwtBearerMiddlewareDiagnosticsEvents: true);
    ...
  }
...
```

In my config the values are as follows:

```
"AzureAD": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "*MY TENANT ID*",
    "ClientId": "*Client ID of API",
    "ClientSecret": "Client Secret for API",
    "Audience": "Client ID of Front End"
}
```

To get auth I followed this tutorial -> [here](https://cmatskas.com/create-a-protected-api-that-calls-in-ms-graph-on-behalf-of-a-power-app/) <- to set up PostMan to use OAuth 2.0 and get the tokens for me automatically. The magic happens at the end of step 3 in the tutorial.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: After following the tutorial like alphaz18 suggested, I found my issue. I had forgotten to add the Authentication middle ware in the `Configure` part of `Startup.cs`.

```cs
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication(); // This line was missing.
            app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: So what is the audience in the token? could you check it matches what you re validating in the backend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend you follow the Microsoft sample tutorials first as they are all working. they give you all steps to get these samples working and is a great place to start:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-spa-aspnetcore-webapi

in that tutorial you posted, I don't see anything about audience either. So where did you get that from?

Comment: I'll go through and do that tutorial now. At a quick glance it looks like exactly what I need. As for the audience it was the error that came up in the debug logs. So I tried adding it in to see if it helped. It did not.

Comment: I've added an Edit to my original post pointing out where I went wrong. I found it after looking at the project you linked. Thanks so much, I had been stuck for a few days.